# 2-way SSL with CherryPy

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, cherrypy, client-certificates

From CherryPy 3.0 and onwards, one-way SSL can be turned on simply by pointing to the server certificate and private key, like this:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello SSL World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate = "keys/server.crt"
cherrypy.server.ssl_private_key = "keys/server.crtkey" 
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This enables clients to validate the server's authenticity. Does anyone know whether CherryPy supports 2-way ssl, e.g. where the server can also check client authenticity by validating a client certificate?

If yes, could anyone give an example how is that done? Or post a reference to an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't out of the box. You'd have to patch the wsgiserver to provide that feature. There is a ticket (and patches) in progress at http://www.cherrypy.org/ticket/1001.

Comment: Now at https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1001/adding-support-for-client-certificate

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for the same thing. I know there are some patches on the CherryPy site.

I also found the following at [CherryPy SSL Client Authentication](http://blog.donet.com/2010/04/06/cherrypy-https-client-authentication/). I haven't compared this vs the CherryPy patches but maybe the info will be helpful.

> We recently needed to develop a quick
>   but resilient REST application and
>   found that CherryPy suited our needs
>   better than other Python networking
>   frameworks, like Twisted. 
>   Unfortunately, its simplicity lacked a
>   key feature we needed, Server/Client
>   SSL certificate validation.  Therefore
>   we spent a few hours writing a few
>   quick modifications to the current
>   release, 3.1.2.  The following code
>   snippets are the modifications we
>   made:

```
cherrypy/_cpserver.py

@@ -55,7 +55,6 @@ instance = None ssl_certificate = None ssl_private_key
= None
+ ssl_ca_certificate = None nodelay = True

def __init__(self):

cherrypy/wsgiserver/__init__.py

@@ -1480,6 +1480,7 @@
# Paths to certificate and private key files ssl_certificate = None ssl_private_key = None
+    ssl_ca_certificate = None

def __init__(self, bind_addr, wsgi_app, numthreads=10, server_name=None, max=-1, request_queue_size=5, timeout=10, shutdown_timeout=5):

@@ -1619,7 +1620,9 @@

self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) if self.nodelay: self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
-        if self.ssl_certificate and self.ssl_private_key:
+        if self.ssl_certificate and self.ssl_private_key and \
+            self.ssl_ca_certificate:
+ if SSL is None: raise ImportError("You must install pyOpenSSL to use HTTPS.")

@@ -1627,6 +1630,11 @@ ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD) ctx.use_privatekey_file(self.ssl_private_key) ctx.use_certificate_file(self.ssl_certificate)
+            x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
+                open(self.ssl_ca_certificate).read())
+            store = ctx.get_cert_store()
+            store.add_cert(x509)
+            ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, lambda *x:True) self.socket = SSLConnection(ctx, self.socket) self.populate_ssl_environ()
```

> The above patches require the
>   inclusion of a new configuration
>   option inside of the CherryPy server
>   configuration,
>   server.ssl_ca_certificate.  This
>   option identifies the certificate
>   authority file that connecting clients
>   will be validated against, if the
>   client does not present a valid client
>   certificate it will close the
>   connection immediately.
>
> Our solution has advantages and
>   disadvantages, the primary advantage
>   being if the connecting client doesn’t
>   present a valid certificate it’s
>   connection is immediately closed. 
>   This is good for security concerns as
>   it does not permit the client any
>   access into the CherryPy application
>   stack.  However, since the restriction
>   is done at the socket level the
>   CherryPy application can never see the
>   client connecting and hence the
>   solution is somewhat inflexible.
>
> An optimal solution would allow the
>   client to connect to the CherryPy
>   socket and send the client certificate
>   up into the application stack.  Then a
>   custom CherryPy Tool would validate
>   the certificate inside of the
>   application stack and close the
>   connection if necessary; unfortunately
>   because of the structure of CherryPy’s
>   pyOpenSSL implementation it is
>   difficult to retrieve the client
>   certificate inside of the application
>   stack.
>
> Of course the patches above should
>   only be used at your own risk.  If you
>   come up with a better solution please
>   let us know.

Answer (score 0):

If the current version of CherryPy does not support client certificate verification, it is possible to configure CherryPy to listen to 127.0.0.1:80, install HAProxy to listen to 443 and verify client side certificates and to forward traffic to 127.0.0.1:80 
HAProxy is simple, light, fast and reliable. 
[An example of HAProxy configuration](https://github.com/danielnuriyev/cherrypy-samples/blob/master/haproxy.cfg)